# Let $f: \mathbb{R}→\mathbb{Z}$, where $f(x)=\lceil2x−1\rceil$.

Tags: functions, inverse, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have $f$ defined from $\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{Z}$, where $f(x)=\lceil2x−1\rceil$.

- We need to find $f(A)$, where $A=\{x \in \mathbb{R}∣1\le x \le4\}$.
- And we also need to find $f^{-1}(B)$, where $B = \{−9,−8\}$.

I don't really understand how to solve this problem. I just need a little help and I'll do the calculations myself.

Comment: Can you calculate $f(x)$ for some values in $A$?  What are the points where the value changes?

Comment: But, @mdave16, $[-9,-8]$ is not a subset of the target space (codomain).

Comment: You're right, i was just being silly!, i'll delete the original one to not confuse others, thanks!

Comment: $f^{-1}$ doesn't even exists or isn't a function.

Comment: @kingW3, it's an abuse of notation, it just means pre-image

Answer (score 1):

By definition we have
$$f(x)=\left\lceil 2x-1\right\rceil=n$$
iff $n-1<2x-1\leq n$, which is the same as
$$f(x)=n\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad{n\over2}<x\leq {n+1\over2}\ .\tag{1}$$
It follows that $f(x)=1$ for ${1\over2}<x\leq1$, that $f(x)=2$ for $1<x\leq{3\over2}$, and so on, until  $f(x)=7$ for ${7\over2}<x\leq4$. This allows to conclude that $f(A)=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$.

On the other hand from $(1)$ it follows that $f(x)=-9$ iff $-{9\over2}<x\leq-4$, and $f(x)=-8$ iff $-4<x\leq-{7\over2}$. This allows to conclude that $f^{-1}(B)=\bigl]-{9\over2},-{7\over2}\bigr]$.